# Retrieving SentEvent and Subscriber

Tags: soap-api, marketing-cloud

Is it possible to retrieve `SentEvent` and `Subscriber` objects in one call to the API.
Right now I get SentEvent by `SendId` and then retrieve `Subscriber`s for that `SentEvent` using `SubscriberKey`.

Comment: Welcome to the community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SentEvent` and `Subscriber` objects are separate, and you would have to retrieve the list of `SubscriberKey`s in order to retrieve the `Subscriber` objects.